# how can convert string to hash using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
list =  "{"mins_spent_in_stor":"{"AM 01:00":0,"AM 02:00":0,"AM 03:00":0,"AM 04:00":0,"AM 05:00":0,"AM 06:00":0,"AM 07:00":0,"AM 08:00":0,"AM 09:00":0,"AM 10:00":0,"AM 11:00":0,"PM 12:00":273,"PM 01:00":0,"PM 02:00":30,"PM 03:00":0,"PM 04:00":0,"PM 05:00":0,"PM 06:00":0,"PM 07:00":0,"PM 08:00":0,"PM 09:00":0,"PM 10:00":0,"PM 11:00":0,"AM 12:00":0}","store_hr_opt":"{"00:0C:66:20:0E:3A":{"AM 01:00":0,"AM 02:00":0,"AM 03:00":0,"AM 04:00":0,"AM 05:00":0,"AM 06:00":0,"AM 07:00":0,"AM 08:00":0,"AM 09:00":0,"AM 10:00":0,"AM 11:00":0,"PM 12:00":5,"PM 01:00":0,"PM 02:00":0,"PM 03:00":0,"PM 04:00":0,"PM 05:00":0,"PM 06:00":0,"PM 07:00":0,"PM 08:00":0,"PM 09:00":0,"PM 10:00":0,"PM 11:00":0,"AM 12:00":0}}"}"
```

I need to convert this string into hash, but when am using this command  JSON.parse(list),  i'm getting this error
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token A,**
Please anyone help me..

Comment: You want to convert it into an *object literal*. You need to [escape your `"` quotes](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html)

Comment: The string isn't valid JSON. Where do you get it from, and can you change its format?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with a couple of replaces:

```
var list =  '{"mins_spent_in_stor":"{"AM 01:00":0,"AM 02:00":0,"AM 03:00":0,"AM 04:00":0,"AM 05:00":0,"AM 06:00":0,"AM 07:00":0,"AM 08:00":0,"AM 09:00":0,"AM 10:00":0,"AM 11:00":0,"PM 12:00":273,"PM 01:00":0,"PM 02:00":30,"PM 03:00":0,"PM 04:00":0,"PM 05:00":0,"PM 06:00":0,"PM 07:00":0,"PM 08:00":0,"PM 09:00":0,"PM 10:00":0,"PM 11:00":0,"AM 12:00":0}","store_hr_opt":"{"00:0C:66:20:0E:3A":{"AM 01:00":0,"AM 02:00":0,"AM 03:00":0,"AM 04:00":0,"AM 05:00":0,"AM 06:00":0,"AM 07:00":0,"AM 08:00":0,"AM 09:00":0,"AM 10:00":0,"AM 11:00":0,"PM 12:00":5,"PM 01:00":0,"PM 02:00":0,"PM 03:00":0,"PM 04:00":0,"PM 05:00":0,"PM 06:00":0,"PM 07:00":0,"PM 08:00":0,"PM 09:00":0,"PM 10:00":0,"PM 11:00":0,"AM 12:00":0}}"}'.replace(/\"\{/g,"{").replace(/}\"/g,"}");
```

But that is by no means an elegant or good solution and is only likely to work on this particular input and will break if you get any other garbled JSON string.

So you should really fix the source of the data.

http://jsonlint.com/ is a nice tool to quickly check if a JSON is valid.